# ZIndex stacking IFRAME and DIV inside a flexbox list

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox, z-index

My question is about stacking two HTML elements (first is an iFrame, second is a div) according to their zIndex inside a DIV that belongs to a flexbox list.

The main HTML is

```
<html>
...
<body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
<div id="0" style="position: relative; order: 0; border-left: none;"><iframe ....></iframe></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is that at a certain point a new DIV is appended to the main item DIV so there are two elements.

```
<html>
...
<body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
<div id="0" style="position: relative; order: 0; border-left: none;"><iframe ....></iframe>
<div id="anotherDiv" style="z-index:1;" .... />
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I need the second element to be on the other (preferably on the right and vertically centered), not after, as I see it is now when rendered.

No matter what style parameters I assign I cannot obtain what I want.

How can this be done?

Comment: Position #anotherDiv absolutely.

Comment: @ravb79 I tried many combinations of style parameters, including the one you suggested but the div gets always laid after its sibling not upon it. The containing div gets enlarged.

Comment: what happens when you position the iframe relatively as well?

Comment: @ravb79 It doesn't change (mainly because the iFrame is inside the div)